# How to customise the CirclePageIndicator?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter` to get a slideshow of `XML`s in android app. I am using [`CirclePageIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to number the page. How can I customise the color of the circle corresponding to current page ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On your `CirclePageIndicator` object call `setPageColor(Color.RED)` to set the default fill colour of the circle to red. Call `setFillColor(Color.BLACK)` to set the fill colour of the selected circle to black. Call `setStrokeColor(Color.WHITE)` to set the stroke or the circle's border colour to white.

You can pick whatever colour you want to customize the indicator, these colour values I provided are just as an example.

You can also customize these indicators using XML.

Example from [Android-ViewPagerIndicator's GitHub repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/themed_circles.xml):

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:fillColor="#FF888888"
    app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF000000" />
```

Comment: @Zortkun: This is the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample

Comment: Is SO stopping you from viewing the *ViewPagerIndicator Sample* app on the Google Play Store? id = `com.viewpagerindicator.sample`

Comment: 'We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.' i donT know what the problem is but..

Comment: Looks like the sample app has been removed from Google Play. I can use the link because I have the app installed on my phone. Anyway here is an APK built from the source code from the GHitHub repo http://d-h.st/0js

Comment: Thanks, is there way to increase distance between indicators!

Comment: @Shubh to increase distance between the circle indicators, you will have to edit the CirclePageIndicator's [onDraw](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java#L198) method. Check out the `threeRadius` variable.

Comment: Yes that is possible solution. In my case I got latest [CirclePageIndicator.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/pull/231) implementation which it self has implementation to maintain using **extraSpacing** parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify, the link to CirclePageIndicator you provided is not the latest version of that class, as it is a pull request to add the *extraSpacing* feature. In any case, the code in the PR will work :) 

Hope @jake-wharton pulls the code change soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom images drawable instead of colors and stroke you can use this library:

https://github.com/augustopicciani/DrawablePageIndicator