# app:something...What is app:?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using [this famous ViewPagerIndicator library](https://github.com/InkApplications/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) in my project. I wanted to add color on `ViewPageIndicator`. I found a solution from [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396113/how-to-customise-the-circlepageindicator).

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:fillColor="#FF888888"
    app:pageColor="#88FF0000"
    app:strokeColor="#FF000000" />
```

But one thing I can't understand here: why it is written `app:` instead of `android:`? What does `app:` mean? I have never used `app:`? What is its namespace? I googled but no solution found.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#additional_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the namespace, add this: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
The app namespace is used for all 'new' attributes. For example: if I make a custom view, that has its own attributes (let's say RainbowView with new attribute 'numberOfColors'), then I have to use that attribute in the app namespace because it isn't declared in the android namespace. So use the app namespace for all custom attributes. Either attrs you defined yourself, or attrs the author of a library added (in your case for CirclePageIndicator). But most of the time, when you start typing 'strokeCo...' and you see 'strokeColor' in the autocomplete list, the namespace will be added automatically when you select it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only need to add the missing namespace:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Or take a look at this answer for referencing a library:

[How can I set up custom namespaces in layout file in Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097961/how-can-i-set-up-custom-namespaces-in-layout-file-in-android-studio)