# Android ViewpagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I have included a circlepageIndiacator to viewpager in xml file.But I do not know what to include in the build.gradle file.Please help me!!
below is the viewpager part in layout where I included it.

mascotlayout.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp">
            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396113/how-to-customise-the-circlepageindicator

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Please read the tutorial ; do google before asking a  question.http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask